# ReconfigExistingLoggers with external file

Tags: xamarin.android, nlog

I use NLog in an Android xamarin project.
I add a base NLog.config file in the asset to make configuration and include under it an external file who I want to set the file directory at runtime with a variable.
Here is an exemple of my config file:

```
<variable name="DataDirectory" value="app_Log"/>
<include file="${var:DataDirectory}/nlog*.config" ignoreErrors="false"/>

 <targets>
    <target name="f1" xsi:type="File"   fileName="${var:DataDirectory}/${shortdate}.log"/>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="f1" />
  </rules>
```

The variable DataDirectory is set at runtime before call the  LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers() function.

All work well for the target, but NLog don't read the external file to merge it.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Olivier

Comment: Show us the code where you set the variable and load your configuration.  What's likely happening is you're setting the variable, then loading the configuration file, which wipes out your variable.

Comment: ReconfigExistingLoggers will only refresh Logger-objects according to the current configuration. It will not attempt to reload the entire configuration. Think your scenario with including additional config files based on global variables is on the edge of NLog. Especially on the Android platform. Think you have to investigate using the NLog internallogger.